# Problems with customizing buttons of a SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am using the older version of SweetAlert (Lower than SweetAlert2). When executing the modal, the main buttons are not working correctly.

The buttons' HTML is generated, but they are not shown.
What is wrong?

Thanks :)

```
swal("A wild Pikachu appeared! What do you want to do?", {
    showConfirmButton: false,
    buttons: {
    cancel: "Run away!",
    catch: {
      text: "Throw Pokéball!",
      value: "catch",
    },
    defeat: true,
  },
})
.then((value) => {
  switch (value) {

    case "defeat":
      swal("Pikachu fainted! You gained 500 XP!");
      break;

    case "catch":
      swal("Gotcha!", "Pikachu was caught!", "success");
      break;

    default:
      swal("Got away safely!");
  }
});
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your generated buttons contains `style="display: none;"` which prevents the button from showing up. Not sure what's causing the issue but you could, as a workaround, define this css:  `.sa-button-container button { display: block !important }`

Comment: @LS, Although the "showConfirmButton" option is set to false, the "OK" button still appears. The buttons were misaligned and only two buttons appeared. I updated the post image ...